# How do I reset a customized shortcut in Xcode 10.x/11.x?

Tags: xcode, keyboard-shortcuts

Once customized, selecting the shortcut shows what the default shortcut was in the status bar at the bottom of the window. When editing the shortcut, I can only type a new shortcut or remove the existing one (leaving the action without any shortcut) but how can I restore the original shortcut?

In some cases typing is not an option. E.g. the default shortcut for `Show Previous Tab` is **^⇧⇥**, yet when I try to type that, I get **^⇧⇤** since when holding down shift, tab becomes a back-tab.

In another case I somehow managed to assign exactly the same shortcut to two actions which usually do share a common shortcut, yet one of both always adds **⎇** key to whatever shortcut the other one has. This is clearly a bug and now when now changing the shortcut for one action, the shortcut for the other one changes alike, so there is always a conflict and the actions never work at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's very easy: Select the customized action(s) and just hit backspace (**←**).

Do not enter shortcut edit mode first as that would set backspace as a new shortcut for the action.